# Extracting specific data from HTML using the HTMLAgilityPack in c#

Tags: c#, html, parsing, webclient, html-agility-pack

I've been trying to extract data from a website by giving it the HTML string.
I did some research and figured out that I had to use the HtmlAgilityPack; however,
I can't figure out how to apply the examples to my case.

I've done different tests but none seem to work.

A webpage example could be
http://www.trivago.com/?aDateRange[arr]=2014-11-02&aDateRange[dep]=2014-11-03&iRoomType=7&iPathId=34741&iGeoDistanceItem=0&iViewType=0&bIsSeoPage=false&bIsSitemap=false&

I would only need to extract the contact data,
address, telephone, the official homepage link and the title of the 
element in the list.

I tried moving through the source with Firebug and the class structure
to get to this data is as follows:

```
class="no-touch"
    class="web10152"
        class="page_wrapper"
            class="main_content"
                class="main"
                    class="centercol content"
                        class="content"
                            class="container_itemlist itemlist_simplified"
                                    class="itemlist hotellist group component"  // Has a List of each item

// Item (undernode of itemlist hotellist group component)                               
class="hotel item bookmarkable historisable"        //item main class

    // Path to get title
    class="cf item_wrapper"
        class="item_prices"
            <h3 title="ITEM TITLE" </h3>

    // Path to get contact info
    class="slideout_wrapper component expand"
        class="slideout_content_container"
            class="slideout_content info item_info js_trivago_info active"
                class="item_info_block contact"     // Contains info
                    <em> ADDRESS INFORMATION </em>
                    <em> TELEPHONE INFO </em>
                    class="partnerHomepageLink link"
                        //Contains Link info
```

I don't know how to communicate this with HtmlAgilityPack.
Here is the last thing i tried...

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(page);
try
{
    var table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//h3[@class='jsheadline js_slideout_trigger js_trackable']/title");

    var table1 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='item_info_block contact']");
    var ele = table1.Elements("em");
}
catch { Program.ChangeColor(Program.TextColors.PROGRAM_ERROR);           
    Console.WriteLine("\nError Report: Failed to parse page!"); 
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: And what's the problem using that code?

Comment: A NullReferencePointer Exception gets thrown.

Comment: @Justingp Be careful because the page it's loaded through AJAX.

Comment: If you just want hotel listings, there are some suggestions in [Public Hotel API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197879/public-hotel-api) which don't need web page scraping.